# Oracle PL/SQL group by issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I want to do this excercise for Oracle 10g Express

> "Write an SQL query to retrieve the department name, firstname,
>   lastname, salary of the employee who earns the maximum salary for that
>   department."

I tried this code but it is not working for me.

There are two tables named employees, departments

ERROR is: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, departments.department_name, salary
FROM employees, departments

where employees.department_id = departments.department_id

group by salary
```

*Output must be like that.*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use an aggregate function to get the result. In this case you will use `max()` to get the highest salary for each department.

There are several ways that this can be written.

You can use a subquery in a join:

```
select d.department_name,
  e.first_name,
  e.last_name,
  e.salary
from employees e
inner join
(
  select max(salary) MaxSalary, department_id
  from employees
  group by department_id
) e1
  on e.department_id = e1.department_id
  and e.salary = e1.maxsalary
inner join departments d
  on e.department_id = d.department_id;
```

Since you are using Oracle, you can use windowing functions to get the result:

```
select department_name, first_name, last_name, salary
from 
(
  select d.department_name,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    e.salary,
    row_number() over(partition by d.department_id order by e.salary desc) rn
  from employees e
  inner join departments d
    on e.department_id = d.department_id
) d
where rn = 1
```

Or you can even use a `WHERE` clause to filter the data:

```
select d.department_name,
  e.first_name,
  e.last_name,
  e.salary
from employees e
inner join departments d
  on e.department_id = d.department_id
where salary in (select max(salary)
                 from employees e1
                 where e.department_id = e1.department_id
                 group by department_id)
```

Comment: yes! thats the answer, especially last solution is very clear for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question that you are asking is in reference to using GROUP BY but I would take a closer look at the question.

"Write an SQL query to retrieve the department name, firstname, lastname, salary of the employee who earns the maximum salary for that department."

I think you would also benefit from looking at the Maximum function since you are looking for the employee with the Maximum salary.

You need an aggregate function to be able to use GROUP BY. Aggregate functions are functions that perform a task over several records. These are functions like SUM, AVG, and COUNT. When you have an aggregate function, you group by whatever is not in the function.

In your example, MAX would be your aggregate function and you can use your GROUP BY successfully.

[Here is a link for Aggregate Functions](http://infogoal.com/sql/sql-aggregate.htm)